# Good way to init array of JavaScript objects and their properties?

Tags: javascript

I know I can init an array of JS objects like this:

```
var things = [
  {
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: 'bar'
  },
  {
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: 'bar'
  }
];
```

I guess I would call these 'anonymous' types (sorry, I'm using C#/.NET language).

What if I want these to be of the same prototype? So I have defined a constructor:

```
var Thing = function Thing() {
};

Thing.prototype.prop1 = 'default value';
Thing.prototype.prop2 = 'default value';
```

Now I want both the items in my original code above to be `Thing`s.  Is there a good way to do this?

If I were to guess, I would say maybe something like:

```
var things = [
  new Thing() {
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: 'bar'
  },
  new Thing() {
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: 'bar'
  }
];
```

Which is basically C# object initializer syntax. What I'm trying to avoid is:

```
var thing1 = new Thing();
thing1.prop1 = 'foo';
thing1.prop2 = 'bar';
var thing2 = new Thing();
thing2.prop1 = 'foo';
thing2.prop2 = 'bar';
var things = [thing1, thing2];
```

---

Edit:

I should also note that my prototypes also contain some functions that are shared. Also in actuality I have arrays nested 3 deep, so its something more like:

```
{
   [
    { 
      [
        {},
        {}
      ]
    },
    {
      [
        {},
        {}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is why I as hoping to just init everything inline like this and not setting each property line by line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var Thing = function(params) {
  this.prop1 = params.prop1;
  this.prop2 = params.prop2;
};

var things = [
  new Thing({
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: 'bar'
  }),
  new Thing({
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: 'bar'
  }),
];
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it worked best in my situation. It also allowed me to do optional properties, like: `function Thing (params) { this.name = params.hasOwnProperty("name") ? params.name : "some default"; }`

Answer (score 11):

You are not making use of your 'constructor'. Its preferred to initialize values IN YOUR CONSTRUCTOR:

```
var Thing = function Thing(prop1, prop2) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;
};
```

and then do:

```
var thing1 = new Thing("foo", "bar");
var thing2 = new Thing("foo", "bar");
```

Comment: I started down this path, but it gets a little odd because some of my properties are also arrays, so I end up with something like: `new One("foo", [new Two([new Three(), new Three()]), new Two([new Three(), new Three()])], "bar")`  which just looks ugly.  I think you are probably right though. I guess I was just trying to retain the property names, for readability.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike, if you're going through the trouble of making a new class, you should probably be sure that you've got a use case for methods on that class. Otherwise, you're better off with object and array literals. Additionally, large amounts of static data are probably better left as a JSON data source.

Answer (score 1):

In this cases I add a "config" method to the object:

```
function Thing() {
}
Thing.prototype.prop1 = 'foo';
Thing.prototype.prop2 = 'bar';
Thing.prototype.config = function(data) {
    for (var i in data)
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i))
            this[i] = data[i];
}

var array = [
    new Thing().config({
        prop1: 'foobar',
        prop2: 'barfoo'
    })
];
```

Comment: Is there a difference between having a `.config()` and doing it in the constructor itself? `function Thing(data) { for (var i in data)
 ... }` which is basically @alcidesqueiroz answer.

Comment: Well, the main difference is than implementing it on the constructor executes the iteration over the object every time you create a `Thing`, doesn't matter if you need it or not, using `.config()` method you implicitly ask for it.

Comment: Also, you can add the method `.config()` to any existing class (but I don't recommend you to extend native Types)

Answer (score 0):

The following may work, is this something you'd want to avoid also?

```
var thing1 = new Thing();
var thing2 = new Thing();

thing1.prototype = {
    prop1: "foo",
    prop2: "bar"
};

thing2.prototype = {
    prop1: "foo",
    prop2: "bar"
};
```

Another thing I can think of is making the constructor yourself so it allows something like the following:

```
var things = [
    new Thing({
        prop1: "foo",
        prop2: "bar"
    }),
    new Thing({
        prop1: "foo",
        prop2: "bar"
    })
];
```

Comment: Wouldn't that change the prototype that each object instance is based on? The prototype also has some shared functions, so wouldn't it loose those too?

Comment: @CodingWithSpike yeah it would =/

Comment: You cannot change the prototype of instances. Constructors have the `.prototype` property, who is referred to the hidden `[[Protototype]]` property of the objects created with this constructors. You cannot change this property (in a standard way), so what the first snippet is doing is adding a property called `prototype` to the instances who must be accessed by `thing1.prototype.prop1` who has nothing to do with `thing1.prop1`